# Compile & Install Mono on Centos - Can't get past 'make'

Tags: mono, centos, gmcs

The basic instructions for installing Mono are:

tar xzvf mono-X.XX.tar.gz; cd mono-X.XX
./configure --prefix=/usr/local; make; make install

So I've downloaded the latest version from http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/ and extracted it (but being that is a bz2, used the j option for tar).

The configure seems to work OK. When I run make, it plugs along for a good 40 minutes or so before this:

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
make[6]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
make[6]: gmcs: Command not found
make[6]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 127
make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
make[6]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
*** The compiler 'gmcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
*** Trying the 'monolite' directory.
make[7]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
make[8]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
Corlib not in sync with this runtime: expected corlib version 102, found 100.
Loaded from: /usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs/class/lib/monolite/mscorlib.dll
Download a newer corlib or a newer runtime at http://www.go-mono.com/daily.
make[8]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 1
make[8]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
make[8]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
*** The contents of your 'monolite' directory may be out-of-date
*** You may want to try 'make get-monolite-latest'
make[8]: *** [do-profile-check-monolite] Error 1
make[8]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.11.2/mcs'
make[7]: *** [do-profile-check] Error 2
```

A few lines later it exits.

I'm at wits end. Endless Googles haven't really got me anywhere except a few people saying that this happens when you overwrite dll's with daily builds.

This is a brand new CentOS 6.2 install with PHP, Apache, Mysql, Webmin and now attempting Mono. I've downloaded the latest mono version (2.11.2), but the same thing happened with the last version (2.11.1).

I'm close to giving up and switching to Debian for our web server, maybe this is the way to go?

Any help appreciated. Cheers

Comment: I had problems installing mono 2.11.1 on CentOs 6.0. The make just stopped at a different place place each time, and the installation never ended. So I did the make folder by folder, and it worked.

Comment: @MiguelMarques: check out the instructions here: http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx they mention bumping the ulimit -v for more virtual memory. maybe that's why you needed to 'divide-and-conquer' it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this same problem. The links in the answer don't work anymore.

A URL that worked for me is: http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-2.11.3.tar.bz2

Answer (score 11):

Running:

```
make get-monolite-latest
```

resolved the problem for me (as your error log suggets)

Comment: yup. this, and then `make ; make install`

Answer (score 1):

I just installed mono-2.11.3 on Centos 6.3.  2.11.3 has an updated monolight version of 104. Try getting it from this link https://wrench.mono-project.com/Wrench/ViewLane.aspx?lane_id=4&host_id=14&revision_id=12176

The updated monolight is there too, however the package was broken so I just grabbed the full mono package and installed that no problem.